# How to prevent multiple times to open a same DataBase in multiple transaction in SQLite Cordova

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova

I'm working on SQLite with AngularJS and Cordova, I wrote one factory into the handle crud operation in my controller. But when starting when database, opening query is fired  and it works properly but on second time it waits for connection, it is showing database is already open and it skips to another method. This is my factory:

```
.factory('dbCache', function ($q) {
    return  {
        getItem: function (a, key) {
            var db, deferred;

            var table;
            if (!isNaN(a))
            {
                sqlite('inside isNaN get');
                table = "tab" + a;
                sqlite('get ===' + table);

            } else
            {
                table = a;
            }
            deferred = $q.defer();
            sqlite('table name ---' + table);
            //  db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "RDSQLiteTest.db", location: '../../../../storage/sdcard1'});
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "SQLiteTest.db", location: '../../../../storage/emulated/0/Bharat'});
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                //  sqlite('transaction data'+JSON.stringify(tx));
                tx.executeSql('create table if not exists ' + table + '(id integer primary key, data text)');

                return tx.executeSql("select * from " + table, [], function (tx, res) {
                    sqlite('selected data from get Item  ' + res.rows.length);
                    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                        sqlite('return success in get ' + res)
                        return deferred.resolve(res);
                    } else {
                        sqlite('return false in get ')
                        return deferred.resolve(false);
                    }
                }, function (error)
                {
                    sqlite('error in select query ' + table)
                });
            }, function (error)
            {
                sqlite('error inn getItem transaction factory  ' + table)
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        setItem: function (a, data1) {
            var table;
            if (!isNaN(a))
            {
                sqlite('inside isNaN set');
                table = "tab" + a;
                printConsole('set ===' + table);
            } else
            {
                table = a;
            }
            sqlite('inside setItem' + table);
            printConsole('data param  ' + JSON.stringify(data1));
            var data = JSON.stringify(data1);
            //  sqlite('data param 1  '+data);
            var db;
            //  db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "RDSQLiteTest.db", location: '../../../../storage/sdcard1'});
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "SQLiteTest.db", location: '../../../../storage/emulated/0/Bharat'});
            sqlite('db data  ' + JSON.stringify(db))
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
                // sqlite('before create table query ----'+JSON.stringify(tx));
                tx.executeSql('create table if not exists ' + table + ' (id integer primary key ,data text)');
                sqlite('after create table query ----' + JSON.stringify(tx));
                //sqlite('table name before select query *****'+table);
                return tx.executeSql("select * from " + table, [], function (tx, res) {
                    // sqlite('table name after select query *****'+table);


                    sqlite('select query  ---' + res.rows.length);
                    if (res.rows.length > 0) {
                        printConsole('rows length is greater 1' + data);
                        sqlite('length is zero  ---' + JSON.stringify(tx));
                        return tx.executeSql("UPDATE " + table + " SET data = '" + data + "'", [], function (tx, res) {

                            sqlite('after update table   ---' + JSON.stringify(res));
                            return true;
                        }, function (error) {
                            sqlite("error while updating ---" + table);
                        });
                    } else {
                        //  sqlite('length is zero  ---'+res.rows.length);
                        return tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO " + table + " (data) VALUES (?)", [data], function (tx, res) {
                            //  sqlite('select query  ---'+JSON.stringify(res));
                            return true;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }, function (error)
            {
                sqlite('error in sqlite create table  ' + table);
            });
            return false;
        },
        removeItem: function (a) {
            sqlite("inside " + table);
            var table;
            if (!isNaN(a))
            {
                sqlite('inside isNaN remove');
                table = "tab" + a;
                sqlite('remove ===' + table);
            } else
            {
                table = a;
            }
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            var db = null;
            function onDeviceReady() {
                sqlite("inside ondevice ");
                db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "SQLiteTest.db", location: '../../../../storage/emulated/0/Bharat'});
                sqlite("db connected ");
                db.transaction(function (transaction) {
                    //   sqlite("inside remove transaction"+transaction);
                    return transaction.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table, [], function (tx, result) {
                        sqlite("result of drop query " + result);
                        // sqlite('Delete successfully');
                        return true;
                    }, function (error) {
                        sqlite('Something went Wrong in dron query ' + table);
                    });
                });
                return false;

            }
            printConsole('after device ready');

        }
    }
});
```